# Form layout breaks if mat-form-field is in a component

Tags: css, angular-material, angular2-template, angular2-forms

If I use mat-form-fields directly in a form, fields are displayed in a "column" flow, as follows

```html
<h1>Form 1</h1>
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field >
  <input matInput  placeholder='Name' value='world' readonly='true'>
</mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field >
  <input matInput  placeholder='Name' value='world' readonly='true'>
</mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field >
  <input matInput  placeholder='Name' value='world' readonly='true'>
</mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field >
  <input matInput  placeholder='Name' value='world' readonly='true'>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

however, if the mat-form-fields are moved to an angular component, the fields are displayed in a row layout

```html
<h1>Form 2</h1>
<form class="example-form1">
  <input-field></input-field>
  <input-field></input-field>
  <input-field></input-field>
  <input-field></input-field>
</form>
```

where the input-field component's template is defined as follows:

```html
<mat-form-field >
  <input matInput  placeholder='Name' value="world" readonly='true'>
</mat-form-field>
```

and this is the end result. Form1 (no angular component) and Form 2(fields angular components)

[image: Same form, with and without components]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3rxbf?embed=1&file=app/input-field.html

Is there any change I should do to my component's CSS?

Comment: In addition to the answer posted by Serg, you might want to change your `input-field` component's `display` style value from the default `inline` to `inline-block` to match `mat-form-field`. This might help make its layout behaviour more consistent with mat-form-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first form has `max-width: 500px;`, forcing the inputs to wrap. Second form takes all available space, which just so happens to be enough for all fields to fit in one row.